# Is a delivery sent, shipped, or dispatched?

Tags: vocabulary

I am a german speaker, looking for the best way to translate a command in our software.

In german the command is called "Lieferung abschicken", and it describes the process of finalizing a delivery in our software.

This command is issued at the moment the delivery is actually physically sent to the the receiving party.

Now, currently we name it "dispatchDelivery" but I kind of feel that is not the best wording for that process/method. Especially, because dispatch sometimes refers to other stuff in programming, like on another more technical level, not so much on a business level.

I think simply "sendDelivery" would be better, maybe also "shipDelivery"?

Google actually gives the most hits when searching for "dispatch delivery", followed by "ship delivery" and last "send delivery".

Comment: Why not just “Deliver” ?

Comment: Despatch/dispatch or ship look fine to me, but in my mind despatchConsignment or despatchOrder would look more natural.

Comment: "Deliver" refers to the handing over at the end of the journey. Sending an item is known as "dispatch". It refers to the start of the journey. "dispatch delivery" makes no sense.

Comment: There's also "transmit".  And "consign", "transfer", "convey", "forward", "express", "post", "route".

Comment: Is this the caption on a button or is it the name of the routine or procedure that the button activates. Don't forget that you can't create compund words on the fly in English as you can in German.

Comment: @BoldBen We need it for both, so the routine would be named 'dispatchDelivery' but the button would be labeled 'Dispatch delivery'.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using **delivery** to mean something physical you are transmitting to another place, then any of those verbs will work: **dispatch**, **ship**, or **send**, with **dispatch** having the most force. **Ship** has the next most force. The real issue is calling the item a **delivery**, but I know very well you don't always get to choose the words that the software uses.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a delivery sent, shipped, or dispatched?

The answer to this is a straightforward "No". It is none of those things.

Deliveries are **made** or **completed**.

You could justifiably ask whether **goods** or **items** are sent, shipped, or dispatched.

Sending and delivering are opposite ends of the process. You cannot send a delivery any more than you can deliver a sending.